# Unable to find the element within frame

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, xpath

i cant click the menu named biometric check list. there's total five frames and i started to read it from first index. getting unable to locate an element error. What might be the reason any idea.

```
     driver.switchTo().frame(1).findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='menu'//li[@id='biometricCheckList'//a[@title='biometric Check List']")).click();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes start at 0, I think you have to chain .frame(0).switchTo().frame(0) until you get to 5. Or do seperate calls five times.

if this is a new application in development, please tell the developers that framesets are depricated and should not be used anymore.